# What is the difference between rollback, backout and strip in the Mercurial Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, rollback

What is the difference between the menu items rollback, backout and strip in the Mercurial Eclipse plugin?

Can I delete the commit in the local repository without modify the files in my workspace with one of this 3 commands?

Or is there another solution how I can commit and push a fix on another part of the project? My current work is not finish and I can not push it. But I must checkin a quick fix for another part of the project.

The only solution that I see is to create a second workspace. But this look like a overkill for me.

Comment: you should limit your questions to one question per question.  Your first and your second/third aren't really related.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

These commands all come from Mercurial itself, and there are plenty of good compare/contrast posts for them.  However, here they are in brief:

- `rollback`: one-level undo.  Will undo the last pull or commit (**can be dangerous**)
- `backout`: create a new commit that is the inverse of a given commit.  Net effect is an undo, but the change remains in your history.
- `strip`: remove (**destroy**) changes from history.  Removing a changeset also removes all of its children, so it can only be used to truncate history, not remove a slice.

All three are very well described here: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html

To your question 2, you could use `strip` to remove the most recent commit and it won't alter you working directory diles.

To your question 3, you can easily make changes on another part of this project:

```
hg commit -m 'commit your half done work'
hg update OLDERCHANGESET # your working directory now is without the half-done-work
.. do that quickfix ...
hg commit -m 'quickfix'
hg push tip # this pushes the tip revision (latest) and its ancestors, but the half-don't work isn't an ancestor so it doesn't get pushed
hg update HALFDONEWORK # you can find the right revision number using "hg heads"
```

That's call an "anonymous branch" and it's a very common way to work.  You do end up committing the half-completed feature, but you can resume it later and you don't have to push it.

This has a great explanation of anonymous branches: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-anonymously

Comment: The answer to question 2 is wrong. strip in Eclipse remove also the changeset from workspace.

Comment: Yikes.  I hope it gives good warnings about that.  `/me reminds himself why he keeps his VCS and his IDE _separate_`

Comment: For the record it does not good give warnings about that, I found this question when trying to find out how to undo it. Oops!

Comment: Use `hg commit --amend` in Mercurial 2.2 and later to amend (redo) the last commit.