# Forgeting/removing a revision from Mercurial repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, revert

This happens to me a lot of times. I make some edition...

```
$ nano module1.c
```

...run some tests...

```
$ make test
OK
```

...and, since the test passed, I commit it:

```
$ hg commit -m "Bug #123 corrected"
```

Then I start another functionality, editing some test:

```
$ nano test/module2.c
```

I want to run the tests, and press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>↑</kbd>) to execute `make test`. Unfortunately, however, I commit the last message again:

```
$ hg commit -m "Bug #123 corrected"
```

So, Is there a way remove this last commit from my Mercurial repository without losing the edits I have made in `test/module2.c`?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760684/mercurial-undo-last-commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `hg help rollback`. Read it carefully, it's dangerous.

Warning: if you continue the false efficiency of letting your fingers get ahead of your brain, `hg rollback` **will** bite you much harder than `hg commit`. If you want to run `make tests` a lot and can't wait .3 seconds for visual data to reach your prefrontal cortex, make yourself an `mt` alias rather than blindly leaping into your command history.

Comment: Well, I hope to have a lot less problems now because I created a hook which runs `make test` at the `pretxcommit` phase of `hg commit` (and it is unlikely that the tests will be passing). Anyway, your answer solved the question and I think my old bad habits will not go out, unfortunately :)