# Delete some files from the commit with Mercurial and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I am using Mercurial with Eclipse. I made a commit and I commited some files which shuld not been commited.

Do you know if there is a possiblity to delete those files from the commit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rollback` (if it's the most recent commit) or `strip` (if it's older) would do it for you.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760684/612265) has more details on these commands.  To do it with MercurialEclipse, right click on your project in Eclipse and do Team-->Undo-->Rollback or Team-->Undo-->Strip.

If those aren't options, you could just remove the files in question and then commit that as a separate changeset.  That would, of course, preserve the fact that those files were once under Mercurial control.  If that is not desirable, [this page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory) lists some more options.  If you go the MQ route, the workflow listed there can be done in MercurialEclipse via the "Mercurial Patch Queue" view.

Comment: Thank you Evan. I tryed with rollback but didn't wotk because i made a pull after the commit. With the strip, the problem is that it will delete all my work after the before last commit, and I have a lot. Is it possible to delete only some commit files from the commit?