# Mercurial (hg) equivalent of git reset (--mixed or --soft)

Tags: mercurial

what would be an equivalent mercurial command (or workflow) for

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

or

```
git reset --soft  HEAD^
```

i.e. I want leave the working tree intact but get the repository back into the state it was before the last commit. Surprisingly I did not find anything useful on stackoverflow or with google.

Note that I cannot use

```
hg rollback
```

as I've done some history rewriting using HistEdit after the last commit.

**Added to clarify:**
After some rebasing and history editing I had ended up with A<--B<--C. Then I used HistEdit to squash B and C together, obtaining A<--C'. Now I want to split up the commit C' (I committed the wrong files in B). I figured the easiest way to do this was to get the repository back to state A (which technically never existed in the repository because of all the rebasing and history editing before hand) and the working tree to the state of C' and then doing two commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial undo last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760684/mercurial-undo-last-commit)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The right way to replicate `git reset --soft HEAD^` (undo the current commit but keep changes in the working copy) is:

```
hg strip --keep -r .
```

`-1` will only work if the commit you want to strip is the very last commit that entered the repository. `.` refers to the currently checked out commit, which is the closest equivalent Mercurial has to Git's `HEAD`.

Note that if `.` has descendants, those will get stripped away too. If you'd like to keep the commit around, then once you have the commit ID, you can instead:

```
hg update .^
hg revert --all -r <commit id>
```

This will update to the commit's parent and then replace the files in the working copy with the versions at that commit.

Comment: Notice: this need hg's MQ extension.

Comment: Mercurial 2.8 and later comes with a dedicated [strip extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension).

Comment: Worked for me! I got a warning that `hg strip` could be deprecated in the future and that I should consider using `hg uncommit` or `hg undo -k`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the more modern and simpler way to do this now is `hg uncommit`. Note this leaves behind an empty commit which can be useful if you want to reuse the commit message later. If you don't, use `hg uncommit --no-keep` to not leave the empty commit.

> hg uncommit [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> uncommit part or all of a local changeset
>
> ```
> This command undoes the effect of a local commit, returning the affected
> files to their uncommitted state. This means that files modified or
> deleted in the changeset will be left unchanged, and so will remain
> modified in the working directory.
>
> If no files are specified, the commit will be left empty, unless --no-keep
> ```