# Revert Mercurial Commit for Merge

Tags: merge, mercurial, bitbucket, revert, mercurial-commit

I am working on a Hg repo in BitBucket. I forked this repo from another main repo.

Here's my scenario:

```
> hg paths

default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/shuwnyuantee/jstock-android-as
yccheok = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/yccheok/jstock-android-as
```

`default` repo is my forked repo. `yccheok` is the main repo I forked from.

I did the below so I am on `drive-wealth` branch of `default` repo.

```
> hg pull
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/shuwnyuantee/jstock-android-as

> hg update drive-wealth
128 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved

> hg branch
drive-wealth


> hg log -l 3
changeset:   2770:a210525cc123
branch:      drive-wealth
tag:         tip
parent:      2769:a0bacd6f326a
parent:      2768:0eb8c0268784
user:        Shuwn Yuan Tee <s.yuan31tee@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Mar 21 16:41:04 2017 +0800
summary:     merge default branch

changeset:   2769:a0bacd6f326a
branch:      drive-wealth
parent:      2676:7571be00648f
user:        Shuwn Yuan Tee <s.yuan31tee@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Mar 21 13:17:14 2017 +0800
summary:     list all accounts API

changeset:   2768:0eb8c0268784
user:        Yan Cheng Cheok <yccheok@yahoo.com>
date:        Sat Mar 18 13:56:51 2017 +0800
summary:     Add the missing tracker name.
```

I wish to revert commit `2770:a210525cc123` on `drive-wealth` branch & push to `default` repo. I tried `hg strip --keep -r .` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112280/mercurial-hg-equivalent-of-git-reset-mixed-or-soft/19064016#19064016). Some files appear as `Modified` as:

```
> hg status
M achartengine/build.gradle
M androidXml/build.gradle
M androidlockpattern/build.gradle
M gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
M jstockandroid/build.gradle
M jstockandroid/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
......
```

My questions are:

1) Those files show changes in Merge, but not all files are `reverted` correctly, many changes are missing / not undone. Any idea?

2) If (1) successfully undo all, then what are steps to proceed? What I want to achieve is => simply revert commit `2770:a210525cc123` on branch `drive-wealth` for `default` repo & push to `default` repo?

Thanks!

Comment: I come from Git background & find Git much easier to use than Hg. I finally migrate my Hg repo to Git by following http://arr.gr/blog/2011/10/bitbucket-converting-hg-repositories-to-git/

Comment: --keep on strip keeps the changes of the commit in the working directory. Probably that's the problem you face?

Answer (score 0):

don't you need to **also** trip 2769?
as 2770 is your merge commit

so

```
hg strip --keep -r 2770
hg strip --keep -r 2769
```

then push

Comment: Don't think so, my intention is to only revert / undo merge commit `2770`. I want to leave commit `2769` as it is.