# Mercurial: roll back an "hg commit --amend".

Tags: mercurial

I accidentally did a "hg commit --amend" instead of just a commit. How can I roll back the commit to before the amend?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is now deprecated.  See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302998/63147) from @Sorina Sandu instead.

---

See [`hg help commit`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/commit), where it says:

> The --amend flag can be used to amend the parent of the working
>   directory with a new commit that contains the changes in the parent in
>   addition to those currently reported by "hg status", if there are any.
>   **The old commit is stored in a backup bundle in ".hg/strip-backup" (see
>   "hg help bundle" and "hg help unbundle" on how to restore it).**

Comment: Please improve this answer by explaining what steps need to be done after the unbundle to actually get to the unamended commit.

Comment: @akuhn, I think it's `hg merge` and then `hg commit -m 'message_for_the_last_commit'`, but it messes the history a bit.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll either just `amend` the newly unbundled `tip` commit itself, so that you can give it a meaningful error message, or you'll do as @oblalex suggested and `merge`. In many cases, you'll end up wanting the commit message of the former tip (left in place by `hg unbundle`) as the message used with the new tip.

Answer (score 65):

You can use `hg reflog` (from the [journal extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension)) and `hg reset <hash>`.

```
hg reflog -v
```

should give something like:

```
<old-hash> -> <new-hash> <user> <timestamp>  commit --amend <some-path>
```

if that is the amend you want to revert, just use:

```
hg reset <old-hash>
```

The commit will be reverted to what is previously was and the changes that were amended should now be uncommitted changes (check using `hg status` and `hg diff`).

Comment: this is a correct answer.  mercurial does support reflog and reset

Comment: @JacobKrall  This works for me perfectly with Mercurial.

Comment: @zzy I think you have enabled an extension providing the `reflog` and `reset` commands. Maybe the experimental `journal` extension?

Comment: @YiZhu what extensions do you have?

Comment: @RishabhMarya what extensions do you have?

Comment: @JacobKrall  I double checked and the extension `journal` is indeed enabled. You are right if that extension provides such commands. To be honest, I don't know what will happen I uninstalled the extensions.

Comment: As of Nov 2017, "This extension is distributed with Mercurial as experimental."

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, and the [journal extension Wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension) does indeed mention these commands, but the actual extension as of Mercurial 4.5 only contains the `hg journal` command. I'm confused.

Comment: as of 2019 it looks like neither `reflog` or `reset` are recognised when the journal extension is enabled, nor are they mentioned in the [journal extension wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension)

Answer (score 15):

If your version of Mercurial is new enough, I believe you should be able to use the `hg unamend` command from the `uncommit` extension that ships with Mercurial. This may require that obsolescence markers are enabled, I'm not sure.

1. Enable the `uncommit` extension, add this to your `~/.hgrc`:

   ```
   [extensions]
   uncommit =
   ```
2. Actually run the unamend:

   ```
   hg unamend
   ```

Comment: Note that a new commit will be created and only the content will be rolled back (history keeps moving forward).

Answer (score 5):

1. Find the latest saved backup in `.hg/strip-backup` directory
2. `hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/<latest backup>`
3. Now you should have two heads - one with the amended commit, other one with two commits (first one - old commit before amending, second one caled: "temporary amend commit for (old commit hash)".
4. if you have `histedit` extension, you can do `hg histedit` on it in order to change it (e.g. select `edit` in order to achieve a state just before the commit, i.e. when you can see all changes using `hg diff`).

Don't forget to strip the old head.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2022, and my attempts to use `hg unamend` have not worked.  `histedit` is too clunky for my purposes, but the solution proposed by mariu52 elsewhere on this page can easily be adapted to work without `histedit`. It relies on the -k option of the `strip` subcommand.

In a nutshell:

1. Find the latest saved backup in the .hg/strip-backup/ directory
2. Run `hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/<latest backup>` where `<latest backup>` signifies the full filename.
3. Run `hg heads` and note the rev number corresponding to the amendment.
   Let's call this $AMENDREV; this is the rev number we will strip in the next step.
4. Run `hg strip -k --rev $AMENDREV`

**Using the `-k` option in the `strip` command is critical.**

**WARNING**: this procedure will in effect erase the memory of any `add` or `remove` commands
that were pending when the `amend` command was executed.

For example, in the transcript below, the `hg add file2` command is effectively
forgotten after the `strip` command is executed.

---

For clarity, here's a transcript based on the above recipe.

```
$ mkdir tmp ; cd tmp
$ ls
$ echo 1 > file1
$ echo 2 > file2
$ hg init
$ ls
file1   file2
$ hg add file1
$ hg commit -m 'one file'
$ hg add file2
$ hg amend -m 'amendment'
saved backup bundle to /tmp/tmp/.hg/strip-backup/d332ee829c21-5a5f23b0-amend.hg
$ hg unbundle -u .hg/strip-backup/d332ee829c21-5a5f23b0-amend.hg
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
new changesets d332ee829c21 (1 drafts)
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
updated to "1a445f3252eb: amendment"
1 other heads for branch "default"
$ hg heads
1[tip]:-1   d332ee829c21   2022-11-09 01:55 -0500   peak
  one file

0   1a445f3252eb   2022-11-09 01:55 -0500   peak
  amendment

$ ls
file1   file2
$ hg strip -k -r 0
saved backup bundle to /tmp/tmp/.hg/strip-backup/1a445f3252eb-bfaab5ec-backup.hg
$ ls
file1   file2
$ hg list
r0:  peak tip 2022-11-09 01:55 -0500
        one file
    file1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

`hg unamend` part of [Mercurial 4.5 (2018-02-01)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive?highlight=%28unamend%29#Mercurial_4.5_.282018-02-01.29).