# How to revert last commits and keep changes in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have three commits 1, 2 and 3. How can I rollback 2 and 3 and still keep the changed files of them??

```
1---2---3

=> 1 and changed files of 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use the `strip` command:

> strip changesets and all their descendants from the repository

with the `--keep` option:

> -k --keep           do not modify working copy during strip

And since `strip` is destructive of history it's not enabled by default.  You enable it by adding these lines to your `~/.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

So in this case you'd do `hg strip --keep 2`

Note: requires Mercurial 2.8 or later.  Before that you need to put `mq =` in the `.hgrc` instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you use TortoiseHg, you can achieve this like that:

1. Enable *strip* extension from **Settings -> Extensions**
2. Give **Strip...** command from  **-> 'Modify History' -> 'Strip'**.
3. Check *Do not modify working copy during strip (-k/--keep)* option.
4. Click **Strip** button.