# Mercurial rollback? Discard all local changes and start again?

Tags: mercurial, rollback

I'm using Mercurial.

I've made a few errors with merging and so on, and just want to abandon all changes I have made (this includes changes committed locally, but never pushed).

How do I abandon everything and make my repo the same as the remote repo.

(ie see image, I want to discard those 5 queued up pushes)

*** note rollback only works on the (single) last transaction

*** my specific problem was that I had made changes to several different branches.

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260667/1256452 (`hg strip`). Note that strip is a built-in extension in all modern Mercurial versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial undo last commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760684/mercurial-undo-last-commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I cloned the repo to a new folder

```
hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo mercurial-repo
```

and then I deleted my old `.hg` folder and replaced it with a known good one from the origin.